# Reading XML's Next elements value

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a very large xml file to parse and get data from it. I am bit unconfident when it comes to nodes and elements parsing and fetching.
Basically, Small part inside large xml is below

```
<fx:SIGNAL ID="dsffds" ho:OID="sdfdfdf">
<ho:SHORT-NAME>SOME_STAT_VALUE</ho:SHORT-NAME>
<ho:LONG-NAME xml:lang="de">SOME German Text</ho:LONG-NAME>
<ho:LONG-NAME xml:lang="en">SOME English Text</ho:LONG-NAME>
<ho:DESC xml:lang="de" TYPE="Standard">LogicalInterface:ACD.POWERTRAIN.SpeedAccelerationDistance[external]@Fahren;</ho:DESC>
<fx:ELEMENT-REVISIONS></fx:ELEMENT-REVISIONS>
<fx:CODING-REF ID-REF="435435xvdx"/>
<fx:MANUFACTURER-EXTENSION xsi:type="acd:MANUFACTURER-SIGNAL-EXTENSION"></fx:MANUFACTURER-EXTENSION>
</fx:SIGNAL>
```

So far I am able to fetch the value of shortname

```
shortname_lst = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ho:SHORT-NAME')
for shortname in shortname_lst:
            print(shortname.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

but i need to do check if short_name is of my interest then only i would want to get long name and desc data.
Big Problem is at times long name or desc elements are not present, easy way was to check of the index position after pushing above data into lists.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: If looks like you are using minidom. lxml has no `getElementsByTagName` method. Please clarify.

Comment: You should either loop `fx:SIGNAL` or use a `XML` Module that's able to to provide the **Parent** of a matching`ho:SHORT-NAME`.